# Error trying to read a file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to read a file in Java, and I am getting an error. Does anyone know a fix for this?

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class datafile{ static void readFile(){
    try {
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("itemslist.dat"));
        String row;
        String column1;
        String column2;
        String column3;
        while((row = bReader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] itemWord = row.split("\t");
            column1 = itemWord[0];
            column2 = itemWord[1];
            column3 = itemWord[2];
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not read properly");
        }
}
}
```

The file I'm trying to read is in the format:

Food Cooked 400

where the spaces are TABS.

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception type IOException
at datafile.readFile(datafile.java:12)
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: I suggest you go to a basic java tutorial and learn about exceptions.

Comment: you are not handling an IOException. Why you not read your Error log?

Answer (score 3):

Like the error says, you need to catch an `IOException` too.

Since `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`, you don't need to explicity catch `FileNotFoundException` unless you want to display a different error message. Change it to:

```
catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("File not read properly");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With Java 7, it is possible to catch multiple exceptions in a single `catch` block as shown below, but it is not necessary in this case because `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There's for need to multicatch, `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`

Comment: true, you can just catch IOException.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not read properly");
 }catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println("input output problem");
 }
```

Currently, your code only handles `FileNotFoundException`, the code can throw `IOException` which you need to handle